# Chrome opening and immediately closing a tab after clicking SOME links

Tags: chrome, browser-extensions

A few days ago I installed OSX 10.8 on a clean disk, and moved some of the old apps and data form the old to the new one.

I've noticed that Chrome exibited an odd behaviour: when clicking *some* links, it opened and immediately closed a new tab, then it correctly displayed the new page.

I've tried in incognito and it didn't happen, so I've proceeded to disable all extensions and it didn't happen, I've re-enabled them all one by one and it still doesn't happen anymore.

What can I do now, in order to discover if it was just an odd bug or something more worrying?

In case it wasn't obvious, I have no clue which kinds of links triggered this behaviour.

Comment: Noticed this as well, probably ad tracking networks trying to work around SOP policies to be able to load up cookies they've previously saved.

Comment: This happens to me with AdBlock, new ad window opens and is immediately closed.

Comment: It would be interesting to track what site was opened in those windows, I am not a chrome expert, but perhaps there is an add-on or debug mode that could allow some insight as to those windows. If you don't mine, some example URLs that exhibit the behavior would make it easier for others to replicate.

Comment: @user2813274 I would like to do that, but as I explained it's not happening anymore, so I don't really know how to duplicate it :/

Comment: @Lohoris I am not sure if you will get a proper answer without it, but perhaps someone else who has the same question can fill in those gaps when it happens to them - that or if it does occur again for you.

Comment: Sounds like a malicious of badly written Chrome extension. Could you zip all of your extensions and mail it to me for further analysis? If all of the extensions are from the Chrome Web Store, posting the 32-character extension ids is also sufficient.

Comment: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome

Comment: @RobW sent you an email with the links. Some are outsite the store: I might also send you a tarball, but in that case I'd need to omit LastPass and Blockchain for obvious reasons, let me know if you need it. After all, a malicious extension after you've installed it could pretend it's from the store when it's really not?

Comment: @Lohoris A malicious extension cannot pretend that it is from the CWS when it is not. And you can safely tar the extensions directory. The static extension files are saved in Extensions/ (Extensions/[extensionid]/[version]/), the extension data is stored elsewhere (in one of the sqlite or leveldb databases, depending on the storage method used by the extension).